# hide detail table(k-detail-cell) when page load in kendo ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I want to hide the detail table when page loaded

but when click on the triangle on master row, it displays

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/detailtemplate.html

that's from the element I detect on firebug.

[image]

Comment: If you just want to hide the detail table, why use the detail template example and just use the basic http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you could add a `style="display: none;"` to the main container for the `detailTemplate`, but that will probably throw the behavior of the Master Row triangle.

```
<div class="tabstrip" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li class="k-state-active">
           Orders
        </li>
        <li>
            Contact Information
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div class="orders"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class='employee-details'>
            <ul>
                <li><label>Country:</label>#= Country #</li>
                <li><label>City:</label>#= City #</li>
                <li><label>Address:</label>#= Address #</li>
                <li><label>Home Phone:</label>#= HomePhone #</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could instead, just hide it on page load with:

```
$('tr.k-master-row + tr.k-detail-row').hide();
```

or, just initialize the grid with the detail rows hidden when databinding occurs (probably the best solution):

```
//...
detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
detailInit: detailInit,
dataBound: function() {
    this.collapseRow(this.tbody.find(">tr.k-master-row"));
},
//...
```

Comment: this.collapseRow(this.tbody.find(">tr.k-master-row")); works, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
                            dataBound: function (e) {
                                var grid = e.sender;

                                items.each(function (e) {
                                    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);

                                    if (dataItem.SubGroups.length == 0)
                                        grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "].k-master-row>.k-hierarchy-cell>a").hide();
                                });
```